# MySQL Заполнение datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Подскажите пожалуйста как заполнить датагрид только со своими колонками.
На данном этапе такая реализация

```
private void BindMySqlData()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            const string @select = "SELECT * FROM customers;";
            _mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(Settings.Default.MySQLConnectionString);
            _mySqlConnection.Open();

            var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            var mySqlDataTable = new DataTable();

            mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(select, _mySqlConnection);
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(mySqlDataTable);

            var mySqlBindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = mySqlDataTable };

            LoggerHelper.Debug("Update user UI - DataGrid Bind running in thred!");

            return mySqlBindingSource;

        }
        catch (MySqlException mysql)
        {
            LoggerHelper.Error("Error connection to DB!", mysql);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            _mySqlConnection?.Close();
        }
    }).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = x.Result;
        BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = x.Result;
            LoggerHelper.Debug("Update user UI - DataGrid Bind!");
        }));
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Заполняет все нормально, но суть в том, что у меня есть свои колонки и не всю инфу я хочу показывать юзеру.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и сделай в запросе нужные поля, плюс сразу и название выведи.
например так:

```
SELECT `id` as "Номер записи",`name` as "Имя чего-то там",`date` as "Дата",`pasport` as "Данные паспорта" from customers
```

Плюс колонки сами назовутся как укажешь в запросе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прятать ненужные колонки, например: `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;`